# Python split a string at an underscore

Tags: python

How do I split a string at the second underscore in Python so that I get something like this

name = this_is_my_name_and_its_cool

split name so I get this `["this_is", "my_name_and_its_cool"]`

Comment: This is not `split` at underscore.

Comment: Why do you split only at the second underscore?

Comment: So how did you determine that the split was going to be at the *second* underscore? Or did you want to split at the 5th from the end?

Comment: Did you ask Google this question yet? I am ultimately positive it will give you some solutions.

Comment: Get the second part after "this_is" and just append "this_is" to the result :)

Comment: Please narrow down your question. It is unclear what you are trying to solve. "I have X and want Y" is not sufficient. Also read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a string with multiple instances of the same delimiter and you want to split at the nth delimiter, ignoring the others.

Here's a solution using just `split` and `join`, without complicated regular expressions. This might be a bit easier to adapt to other delimiters and particularly other values of `n`.

```
def split_at(s, c, n):
    words = s.split(c)
    return c.join(words[:n]), c.join(words[n:])
```

Example:

```
>>> split_at('this_is_my_name_and_its_cool', '_', 2)
('this_is', 'my_name_and_its_cool')
```

Comment: This is what I ended up using. I am writing tools for Maya a 3D software and this function is now in a shared utilities script where I can use it in all my scripts. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

the following statement will split name into a list of strings

```
a=name.split("_")
```

you can combine whatever strings you want using join, in this case using the first two words

```
b="_".join(a[:2])
c="_".join(a[2:])
```

maybe you can write a small function that takes as argument the number of words (n) after which you want to split

```
def func(name, n):
    a=name.split("_")
    b="_".join(a[:n])
    c="_".join(a[n:])
    return [b,c]
```

Comment: With `n` and `n+1`, you are losing  a word (the upper bound is exclusive)

Comment: Please correct the syntax of the following passage `c="_",join(a[2:])` into `c="_".join(a[2:])`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying the split the string based on second underscore. If yes, then you used use `findall` function.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "this_is_my_name_and_its_cool"
>>> re.findall(r'^[^_]*_[^_]*|[^_].*$', s)
['this_is', 'my_name_and_its_cool']
>>> [i for i in re.findall(r'^[^_]*_[^_]*|(?!_).*$', s) if i]
['this_is', 'my_name_and_its_cool']
```

Comment: @Willy edit your question to say that you're trying to split the input based on the second `_` symbol.

Comment: @Willy [Accept any one or the answers from here which helped you the most.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
print re.split(r"(^[^_]+_[^_]+)_","this_is_my_name_and_its_cool")
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick & dirty way to do it:

```
s = 'this_is_my_name_and_its_cool'
i = s.find('_'); i = s.find('_', i+1)
print [s[:i], s[i+1:]]
```

**output**

```
['this_is', 'my_name_and_its_cool']
```

You could generalize this approach to split on the nth separator by putting the `find()` into a loop.